# How to print a blank line from within a function?

Tags: r, function, printing, cat

I want to write a function to print some output with blank lines in between. Using examples such as `surv:::print.coxph`, I saw that this can be done using `cat("\n")`. however, when I try that in a function, only the first `cat("\n")` gives a blank line as output, while the second does not. Here's an example:

```
prnt.test <- function(x){
  cat("\n")
  cat(x)
  cat("\n")
  cat(x)
}

prnt.test(x="test")

# Output:

test
test
```

Any ideas on how to print a blank line within the two `test`'s?

(I'm using RStudio Version 0.98.501, R version 3.0.2 under Windows: Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit))

Many thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should cat a newline character twice. By writing `cat(x); cat('\n'); cat(x)`, with `x=="test"` you if fact `print("test\ntest")` -- there's only one newline here.

A possible solution:

```
prnt.test <- function(x){
   cat(x, sep="\n\n")
}
prnt.test(c("test1", "test2", "test3"))
## test1
## 
## test2
##
## test3
```